# Remove field reference from content type programmatically (CSOM)

Tags: sharepoint, csom

the title says it all. how can i programmatically remove a field reference from a content type?

what i've tried so far:

```
    public void RemoveField(ClientContext ctx, Web web, ContentType type, Field field) // doesnt do anything
    {
        try
        {
            FieldLinkCollection fields = type.FieldLinks;
            FieldLink remove_field = fields.GetById(field.Id);
            remove_field.DeleteObject();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

this doesnt do anything (also no exception).

i've found another way in a forum:

```
contentType.FieldLinks.Delete(field.Title);
contentType.Update();
```

but the Delete(field.Title) method doesnt seem to exist in the CSOM.

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since content type is being modified, the method for updating content type ([ContentType.Update method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.contenttype.update.aspx)) have to be explicitly invoked:

```
//the remaining code is omitted for clarity..
remove_field.DeleteObject();
ctx.Update(true);  //<-- update content type
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

The following example demonstrates how to *delete* site column from content type using CSOM

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{

    var contentType = ctx.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes.GetById(ctId);
    var fieldLinks = contentType.FieldLinks;
    var fieldLinkToRemove = fieldLinks.GetById(fieldId);
    fieldLinkToRemove.DeleteObject();
    contentType.Update(true); //push changes
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my final working code:

```
    public void RemoveField(ClientContext ctx, Web web, ContentType type, Field field) // doesnt do anything
    {
        try
        {
            FieldLinkCollection flinks = type.FieldLinks;
            FieldLink remove_flink = flinks.GetById(field.Id);
            remove_flink.DeleteObject();
            type.Update(true);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```